10 examples of complex infix / circumfix words which also contain prefixes and/or suffixes (cross language)?
I am putting together a cheatsheet of complex word forms across languages, so myself and others if so desired want to have a test suite of words to work with to figure out how to handle their complex morphology (when building a multilingual spell-checker, for example).
Below is the table copy/pasted in its current form from the link above. Most of the non-English words I got from Claude AI, so while they might be error-prone, they at least demonstrate some word complexity, however correct. Toward the bottom of the table are words which contain both circumfixes and infixes, wow! Specifically the maguindanao language lines (not even sure how the AI got ahold of these possible examples!). The malay ones also offer some complex circumfix + infix examples.
What I would like to do is refine/refactor/improve this list, to include 10 complex examples of words, and make sure they are real or more accurate, if these are errored. The words should include either:

Circumfixes and infixes (as well as suffixes and/or prefixes in addition). This is the most complex case. Ideally we can have 5 examples of this.
Circumfixes with prefixes/suffixes. Ideally 2-3 examples of this.
Infixes with prefixes/suffixes. Ideally 2-3 examples of this.




language
type
unit
meaning




english
word
unwholesomely




prefix
un-




word
whole




suffix
-some




suffix
-ly



english
word
creativity




word
create




suffix
-ivity



english
word
creates




word
create




suffix
-s



english
word
creation



english
word
ability



english
word
abilities




word
ability




suffix
-s



english
word
flip



english
word
flipper




word
flip




suffix
-er



english
word
flipping




word
flip




suffix
-ing



english
word
flippant



english
word
beauty



english
word
beautiful




word
beauty




suffix
-ful



english
word
dichromatic




prefix
di-




word
chromatic



sanskrit
word
sarva-jana-sukha-pradāyakam
That which gives happiness to all people



base
sarva
all



base
jana
people



base
sukha
happiness



base
pradāyaka
giver



compound
sarva-jana
all people



compound
sukha-pradāyaka
happiness giver



suffix
-m
(accusative case ending)


sanskrit
word
pra-ati-divasa-kṛta-prayogaḥ
The usage done every day



prefix
pra-
forth



prefix
ati-
beyond



base
divasa
day



base
kṛta
done



base
prayoga
usage



compound
pra-ati-divasa
every day



compound
kṛta-prayoga
done usage



suffix
-ḥ
(nominative singular case ending)


sanskrit
word
sam-yak-jñāna-vat-purāṇaḥ
The ancient one possessing complete knowledge



prefix
sam-
completely



prefix
yak-
together



base
jñāna
knowledge



base
vat
possessing



base
purāṇa
ancient



compound
sam-yak-jñāna
complete knowledge



compound
jñāna-vat
possessing knowledge



suffix
-ḥ
(nominative singular case ending)


sanskrit
word
dur-ava-gamya-śakti-yukta-mānavaḥ
A human endowed with power that is difficult to understand


tagalog
word
sumulat
wrote



base
sulat
to write



infix
-um-
(past tense)


sudanese arabic
word
katatab
to write repeatedly



base
katab
to write



infix
-ta-
(repeatedly)


mikasuki
word
waholin
to shout repeatedly



base
walin
to shout



infix
-ho-
(repeatedly)


german
word
ge-sag-t
past participle of "to say"



base
sagen
to say



circumfix
ge-*-t
(past participle)


dutch
word
ge-fiets-t
(past participle of "to cycle")



base
fietsen
to cycle



circumfix
ge-*-t
(past participle)


malay
word
ke-benar-an
truth



base
benar
true



circumfix
ke-*-an



indonesian
word
ke-hidup-an
life



base
hidup
alive



circumfix
ke-*-an



turoyo
word
m-shaql-o
taken



base
shaqil
to take



circumfix
m-*-o
(past participle)


turoyo
word
m-damy-o
slept



base
damikh
to sleep



circumfix
m-o
(past participle)


turkish
word
ev-ler-imiz-de-ki-ler
those in our houses



base
ev
house



suffix
-ler
(plural)



suffix
-imiz
(1st person plural possessive)



suffix
-de
(locative case)



suffix
-ki
(attributive)



suffix
-ler
(plural)


hungarian
word
város-ok-ban
in cities



base
város
city



suffix
-ok
(plural)



suffix
-ban
(inessive case)


swahili
word
ni-li-som-e-a
I read for



prefix
ni-
(1st person singular subject)



prefix
li-
(past tense)



base
soma
read



suffix
-e
(applicative)



suffix
-a
(final vowel)


finnish
word
talo-i-ssa-mme-kin
also in our houses



suffix
-i
(plural)



suffix
-ssa
(inessive case)



suffix
-mme
(1st person plural possessive)



suffix
-kin
(emphasis)


maguindanao (philippines)
word
pakasimbaungan
to be used to worship



prefix
paka-
(causative marker)



infix
-in-
(aspect marker)



base
simba
worship



suffix
-ung
(verb former)



suffix
-an
(locative marker)


maguindanao
word
kapagisulsulan
teaching repeatedly



prefix
ka-
(noun former)



circumfix
-pag-*-an-
(locative focus marker)



infix
-i-
(aspect marker)



base
sulsul
teach


sundanese
word
dipirumpanicakeun
to be made similar to each other



prefix
di-
(passive voice marker)



circumfix
-pi-*-ca-
(causative marker)



base
rumpani
similar



suffix
-keun
(benefactive marker)


malay
word
mempersatukannya
to unite it



prefix
mem-
(active voice marker)



circumfix
-per-*-kan-
(causative marker)



base
satu
one



suffix
-nya
(third person singular possessive)


malay
word
mempertingkatkan
to increase or enhance



prefix
mem-
(active voice marker)



circumfix
-per-*-kan-
(causative marker)



infix
-t-
(epenthetic consonant, inserted for phonological reasons)



base
ingkat
high




"the AI got ahold of these possible examples" is a fundamental misunderstanding of how LLMs work. It did not get hold of examples, it produced text that statistically looks like examples. They may be genuine, they may not, but it is not certain they are drawn from any source at all

also a lot of these breakdowns are suspect at best (even within English it fails to reliablybreak things down into individual morphemes). As this tool is so clearly unsuitable to producing genuine examples for you to use you should either find a tool that is suitable or else just use nonces instead

as such I'm voting to close, because the only way to make this work is for us to come up with a list of such words, and requests for word lists like that are typically considered off-topic

As for the last word in the chart, there's no such Malay word as *ingkat, -t- is not an infix but the first sound of the root noun tingkat “level, floor/storey”.

Lingála, násálisa "I might have him make something" and nasálísá "I had him make something".

ná-sál-is-a
SUBJ-1S-make-CAUS-∅-SUBJ

Wait, how are there six morphemes in the gloss but only four in the word itself? Well, the tense is conveyed by the tones. -sál- (with an inherent high tone) means "make", na- means "I", -is- makes it causative, and -a is a final vowel inserted for phonological reasons. The subjunctive is conveyed by putting high tone on all prefixes and low tone on all suffixes—contrast nasálísá "I had him make something" in the ultimate past (prefixes low, suffixes high).
